# PHP Not Running On Page Until Refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

bit of a strange one that I've not been able to resolve for months so I finally have given in and have come here for the answer. Hopefully.

I have the below shortcode that when ran returns the phone number depending on what variable has a value. This PHP code works as expected, the one thing that doesn't work as expected however, is the first ever page load.

When someone goes to the site for the first time (or in incognito mode) the shortcode doesn't output anything, however, refresh the page just once and it'll display the output of the correct value and I have no idea why.

```
<?php function gw_cookie($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "value" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $getVariable = isset($_GET[$value]) ? $_GET[$value] : '';
    $newGetVariable = str_replace('_', ' ', $getVariable);

    $cookiePhone = isset($_COOKIE[$value]) ? $_COOKIE[$value] : '';

    $acfField = get_field('page_cookie_'.$value.'');
    $optionsACF = get_field('options_company_details', 'options');

    $area = $optionsACF['options_area'];
    $phone = $optionsACF['options_telephone'];

    if(!empty($cookiePhone) && $cookiePhone !== 'undefined') { //If cookie is not empty do the following
        echo '1';
    } elseif(!empty($newGetVariable)) { //If cookie is empty and get variable is not
        echo '2';
    } elseif($acfField) { //If ACF field is not empty do the following
        echo '3';
    } elseif ($value == "phone") {
        return '4';
    }
} add_shortcode("gw-cookie", "gw_cookie");
```

This codes file is being imported into the functions.php file using the following line:

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/shortcodes/gw-cookies.php' );
```

Comment: a cookie itself would be created on the first run and your criteria requires `cookiePhone` which is why you have to refresh to make it work.

Comment: @Mech i thought that it might be cookie related, is the anyway for me to check if cookie exists and skip it if it doesnt? Without the refresh needing to happen as the cookie is created using JS.

Comment: I think you'd be on the right track with `$cookiePhone = isset($_COOKIE[$value]) ? $_COOKIE[$value] : '';` but perhaps change the `FALSE` value to something like `NULL`?

Comment: @Mech is right... but, there is possibly a second piece since you're probably expecting to see the shortcode output "1". However, I wonder if you're unintentionally mixing up "echo" versus "return". In a shortcode, "return" will put the string at the location of the shortcode; whereas, "echo" will put the string at some random spot on the page (which may not be visible).

Comment: Changing it to NULL on the end of the argument fixed it, thank you ever so much :)

Comment: Glad to help. I'll add it as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cookie itself would be created on the first run and your criteria requires `cookiePhone` which is why you have to refresh to make it work.

As per the comments, change:

```
$cookiePhone = isset($_COOKIE[$value]) ? $_COOKIE[$value] : '';
```

to:

```
$cookiePhone = isset($_COOKIE[$value]) ? $_COOKIE[$value] : NULL;
```